# How to pass an bash command line argument to sed -n p?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to output a specific line from bash argument using `sed`, I have tried many ways, but none work:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n '$2p' $1 
sed -n '${2}p' $1 
sed -n "$2p" $1 
sed -n "${2}p" $1 
sed -n ''"$2"'p' $1
```

How on earth do I get the correct result?

Comment: last three commands shown should have worked, perhaps something else is the problem? try `sed -n "$2p" $1` and give us more details about what is going wrong.. do you get an error msg? if so, add that msg here..

Comment: thanks, now I know where the problem is: I just name the script as "show", and change the permission to 755 and put it in my bin path. When I directly execute it as: show file.txt 3, it doesn't work. But if I change its name as "show.sh" and run it as "sh show.sh file.txt 3", it just work. So why?

Comment: try `./show file.txt 3` or `./show.sh file.txt 3` (whichever is the name you are using, `./` means current directory)... for bin to work, that must be part of `PATH` variable

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed -n "$2p" $1
```

Demo:

```
$seq 10 > file.txt
$cat temp.ksh 
#!/bin/bash
set -x
sed -n "$2p" $1
$./temp.ksh  file.txt 3
+ sed -n 3p file.txt
3
$
```

Comment: thanks, now I know where the problem is: I just name the script as "show", and change the permission to 755 and put it in my bin path. When I directly execute it as: show file.txt 3, it doesn't work. But if I change its name as "show.sh" and run it as "sh show.sh file.txt 3", it just work. So why?

Comment: Check what is current shell you are using. `echo $0`. When you execute `sh blah blah` it opens a new `sh` shell.